# How To Layout a Grid in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to layout a page, but I can't figure out how to do it without tables.  I know it must be possible, but I can't think of a solution that isn't table-based that isn't incredibly rigid with fixed widths for everything.

Mockup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THwhw.png

No matter what I do, it looks like I'm going to have commit a major sin.  For example, the top set - it looks like I'm going to have either to:

1. Create a table (the root of all evil, apparently)
2. Hardcode widths and heights specifically for these elements. (either #id or style= or single-use classes, all three are also considered evil)

Is that the case?  Is there a realistic way I can avoid those scenarios?  Googling for answers just gets me a bunch of useless "TABLES ARE EVIL SO ARE CSS TABLES ALSO DON'T USE ID SELECTORS OR STYLE ATTRIBUTES EVERYTHING MUST BE A REUSABLE CLASS" with no actual useful information.

EDIT: I've already done this with CSS tables (display: table) and had it thrown back as unacceptable.  I think it's fine because it works and it still looks good, but it's not my call.

Comment: I don't think tables are necessarily evil if you're in fact displaying tabular data, such as a grid.

Comment: I've already laid this out using CSS tables and had a web designer yell at me.  They really, really don't want to see any tables.  I'm completely stumped.  :-/

Comment: Semantically, tables should be used for tabular data. They shouldn't be used for layout. In your case, it doesn't seem like you have tabular data, and as such you shouldn't use a table. That's probably why the designer was yelling at you.

Comment: The problem, DC, is the layout.  She also wants everything to align pixel perfect to that mockup.  So I'm either going to have to use tables or hardcode everything what I can tell.  In my opinion, if it looks right, renders wells, and degrades gracefully, it doesn't matter if it's a table or whatever.

Comment: If it has to be pixel perfect, wouldn't the dimensions **have** to be hard coded? What you want to do can easily be done without tables or css "pseudo tables".

Comment: Tell your designers they're retarded (ok, you don't have to say *that*) and have unrealistic expectations.  "CSS tables" is a misnomer.  The display properties that give you the behavior of specific table elements don't actually make an element into a table.

Comment: Rather than argue, I just followed user985723's advice threw the twitter scaffolding at them.  I think it's overkill, personally, but I'm not in charge.  Whatever, I just want something that works.  I could not careless about these mystical rules.  They might have had some merit back in the days of spacer gifs and CSS 1.0 when people were still ignorant of other alignment options, but I personally don't see why using a table to align elements across an entire page that is laid out like a table is an unforgivable sign worthy of eternal damnation.

Comment: Haha, well, maybe not eternal damnation, but I believe the problem with using tables for design comes with users who need screen readers, display no CSS, and somewhat for SEO (if done way wrong). Content generally flows top to bottom and with tables, it doesn't. If content is out of order when the CSS is not present, it can lead to some big challenges for people and search bots. Now, certainly some places you should use tables - pricing sheets and time cards, depending on the design -but for the whole layout it's frowned upon.

Comment: Doug, what about designs like the mockup?  They fortunately gave up on "pixel perfect" when presented the Twitter stuff, but just looking at it... I don't see how it could be done in a flexible way without using a table or display: table somewhere.  You're trying to force items to align to a grid, so it seems like you have two choices: Hardcode the widths and heights of EVERYTHING and have everything break the moment something needs to change in size or use some sort of table-like layout that's flexible but isn't considered "semantically correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables aren't evil. This stackexchange page alone has many tables on it. Some people want to use divs to create rows and spans using a grid. I suggest using tables where they seem appropriate. If you're really bent on avoiding it, consider grabbing something like bootstrap for twitter.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem
There you can use their scaffolding to arrange items the way you want without tables.

Comment: Oh!  I like it.  I'll run it past the web guys and see if they think that's acceptable.

Comment: They weren't very happy with how the stylesheets there have "hardcoded percentages", but saying that it's what Twitter used seem to put the kabosh on any complaints.  If it's good enough for them, it's more than good enough for us.  I think it's ridiculous overkill, but hey, I'm not in charge.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

heres a link on [HTML Tables – when and how to use tables in HTML](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/html-tables/)
this might help you understand when to use tables.

on your mock theres no reason not to use tables. like wordpress backend uses tables for forms but in tabular form.

but if you really want to layout this on divs i rather suggest using css grid frameworks.
I personally use zurb foundation. [heres the link](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Bootstrap, it gives you plenty of options for styling forms. (However it may interfere with the rest of your CSS.)

Here's how a two column form would work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="row">

  <!-- right column -->
  <div class="span6">
    <label>Subject <input type="text"></label>
    <label>Category <select></select></label>
    <label><input type="radio"> Permanent Change</label>
    <label><input type="radio"> Temporary Change</label>
  </div>

  <!-- right column -->
  <div class="span6">
    <label>Requested Approval Date <input type="text"></label>
    Effective Dates <input type="text"> to <input type="text">
  </div>

</div>
```

Obviously the styling leaves a lot to be desired, but check out http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms to see how much you can do. You'll want to look into `<form class="form-horizontal">`. Be forewarned that the CSS is picky, you'll need a lot of `<div class="control-group">`'s.

Comment: Actually, that's a curious point.  If HTML is supposed to be "semantically correct", and this bootstrap stuff is making me litter my markup with tons of wrapper divs, isn't that defeating one the commandments?  "Thou Shalt Write Only Semantically Meaningful Markup"?  What's the semantic meaning of jamming div class="" everywhere to overcome browser limitations?